Crontab not creating log file as root user
I have created crontab as root this is the cron command -
5 * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/path/ && sudo python3 /home/ubuntu/path/main.py > /home/ubuntu/path/anomaly.log 2>&1

However the log file is not generating. What can I do here?

That crontab looks very weird to me for a number of reasons.   First thing I'd do is get rid of the "sudo".  If you are executing it as root, you don't need to use sudo to become root.   If that does not work, what happens if you instead edit /etc/crontab  (remember to add "root" as the user parameter).

Also, I'm not a python expert, but does root and the ubuntu user not have different dependency paths/libraries?  Why are you running something as root from the user home directory?

@Davigo they do, root and ubuntu user are two separate user with their own repertory path, btu right now it's hard to tell the issue without the error message or more detail
